# Fuel filler pipe issue

Tags: fuel-tank

A wasp nest fell down my fuel filler pipe (don't ask). I need to know how hard it will be to take the fuel filler pipe off so I can get the wasp nest out? Can't put gas in my car until i do. 
Any Suggestions Would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model of the car?

Comment: Was this a paper wasp, dirt dauber or what? Can you still see the nest?

Comment: Filler pipe removal difficulty varies with make, model and year of vehicle, no way to answer this question until you post the make, model and year of vehicle.

Comment: With the danger of bits going further, you should also consider having the tank cleaned before you run the car again - don't run the engine as the fuel system could ingest stuff that could cause a lot of damage.

Comment: Paper wasp, no you can't see it.

Comment: 2006 Ford Escape.